# Is it possible to access Spring MVC annotated session vars across multiple controllers?

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, controller, session-variables

I have a web app running Spring 3.0 and using Spring-MVC. I have a few controllers set up like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@SessionAttributes({"clientLogin", "selectTab", "user", "redirectUrl"})
public class AdminController {
...
}

@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"clientLogin", "selectTab", "user", "redirectUrl"})
public class PublicController {
....
}
```

I can add the annotated variables into the ModelMap with something like

```
map.addAttribute("user", "Bob");
```

That works fine to persist the variable in the current controller; I can access the var from the modelMap from any other method in that controller. But when the user hits a page in another Controller, even though the same variable is listed in the @SessionAttributes, it's not available in the second controller.

Is it possible to access these annotated variables across multiple controllers using the annotations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it isn't possible - SessionAttributes are badly named in my opinion.

If you want to share these attributes across different controllers, you can explicitly put them into the session using:

session.setAttribute()

Comment: Here's a link to a related discussion I had that you might find interesting: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=77305

Comment: That is interesting, thanks. Given the trouble you've had (though it seems to have changed from Spring 2.5 to 3.0) do you even attempt to use SessionAttributes anymore?

Comment: They are good for the purpose they have been designed for - simple request-response interactions. If you find you are using lots of conversational style flows with multiple controllers, then Spring MVC isn't really designed for this - you should look into Spring Webflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parent class BaseController which need not be a @Controller class and use the variable `@SessionAttibutes({"clientLogin", "selectTab", "user", "redirectUrl"})` over there. Remember that this class should fall in the scan package of MVC. Then when you need to use this in your actual controllers use as shown below.

```
public String getAllDetails(@ModelAttributes("clientLogin") Client client){
    client.getName();
    return "somejsp";
}
```