# My form bean in @SessionAttributes unkown

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a form bean that I want to store in session so in controller that contain the welcome handler i put this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"searchcontact","cities"})
```

my form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="searchcontact"  ... >
...
<form:options  items="${cities}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
```

I got this error just with attribute `searchcontact` :

```
Etat HTTP 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'searchcontact' available as request attribute
```

the attribute `cities` can be accessed in all session.

Answer (score 0):

`@SessionAttributes` [is not meant to store data across controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934477/is-it-possible-to-access-spring-mvc-annotated-session-vars-across-multiple-contr). It is meant to store data between requests for a given controller.

For storing data in session for access by other controllers, use `HttpSession.setAttribute()`.

Comment: not true read [this](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/), data in `@SessionAttributes` are added into session (`HttpSession`)

Comment: It may add data to `HttpSession` but it's intended to be used within the context of a particular controller conversation. Can you post the controller code that renders the "searchcontact" form?

Comment: i have a search section that i load in every jsp page, i found the problem where come from -> the `searchcontact` i copied in request also but just with handlers of my controller annotated by `@SessionAttributes({"searchcontact","cities"})` in the other controllers even the bean `searchcontact` is stored in session, spring or jsp process look for him in request and don't find him.